# singly linked list push function error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14, unique-ptr

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I have problems with push function. Could you help me?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
using namespace std;

struct lista {
    int value;
    unique_ptr<lista>next;

    lista(int value):value(value), next(nullptr){}


};
void push(int x, unique_ptr<lista> &h) {
    unique_ptr<lista>alok_pam_x = make_unique<lista>(x);
    if (alok_pam_x!= nullptr)
    {
        (alok_pam_x->next) = h;
        h = alok_pam_x;

    }

}
```

And I have the error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error C2280   'std::unique_ptr>
>   &std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::operator =(const
>   std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to
>   reference a deleted function
>   Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
>   (active)      function "std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx>::operator=(const
>   std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx>::_Myt &) [with _Ty=lista,
>   _Dx=std::default_delete]" (declared at line 1436 of "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\memory") cannot be
>   referenced -- it is a deleted function

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to copy `unique_ptr` in two places, but a `unique_ptr` is a move only type, it cannot be copied. You need to [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) it instead.

Also, the check for `nullptr` after calling `make_unique` is pointless because if the allocation fails, it'll throw `std::bad_alloc` and the check will never be reached.

So your `push` function should look like this

```
void push(int x, unique_ptr<lista> &h) {
    auto alok_pam_x = make_unique<lista>(x);
    alok_pam_x->next = move(h);
    h = move(alok_pam_x);
}
```

Finally, you should probably consider making `push` a member function of `lista`.